# How to load texture to main memory on a separate thread and use it to render on the other?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, textures

I am creating a new application and I want to support multithreaded textures loading. How can I load a texture to main memory on a separate thread?

I am using SDL2 to load png files. I have created a thread safe queue class, loaded image into `SDL_Surface surface` with `IMG_Load` function, pushed surface to the queue and if queue is not empty I got the pushed surface's pixels and add it to texture buffer - `glTexImage2D()`

I tried to put a break point on `LoadingThread` function and on `Texture::LoadFromFile()`, but the breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debuggers's target code type is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimization, target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type. I am running on debug(optimizations disabled) 64 bit.

```
template<typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue
{
public:
    ThreadSafeQueue() {}
    ~ThreadSafeQueue() {}

    void Push(T d)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mutex);

        data.push(std::move(d));

        locker.unlock();

        cond.notify_one();
    }

    T* get()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mutex);

        cond.wait(locker, [=]() { return stop || !data.empty(); });

        if (stop && data.empty()) {
            nullptr;
        }

        T res = std::move(data.front());
        data.pop();

        return &res;
    }

    bool Empty()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
        return data.empty();
    }

    std::queue<T> data;

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    bool stop = false;
};

ThreadSafeQueue<SDL_Surface*> queue;
void LoadingThread(const std::string& path) 
{
    SDL_Surface* surf = std::async(std::launch::async, IMG_Load, path.c_str()).get();
    queue.Push(surf);
}

void Texture::LoadFromFile(const std::string& path)
{
    LoadingThread(path);
    SDL_Surface* surface = nullptr;

    if (!queue.data.empty() && path != "") {
        surface = *queue.get();
        if(surface) {
            w = surface->w;
            h = surface->h;
            pixels = surface->pixels;
        } else return;
    } else return;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}


void Draw() 
{
    drawThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>([&]() {
        drawContext->MakeCurrent();
        renderer2D.Create(window);

        std::unique_ptr<Texture> texture = Texture::LoadPNG("Textures/test.png");

        while (!quit) {
            //glClearColor - I prefere 0 - 255 format
            Renderer::ClearColor(sinf(SDL_GetTicks() / 500.0f) * 255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f);
            //glClear() color buffer bit default
            Renderer::ClearBuffers();

            //simple batch renderer 
            renderer2D.RenderClear();
            renderer2D->Draw(texture, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f });
            renderer2D.RenderPresent();

            window.SwapWindows();
        }
    });
}
```

Right now, program stops and wait until the texture is loaded and rendered. I want it to run while the texture is loading and when the texture gets loaded, program will render the texture (rendering is not a problem).

Comment: Unrelated to my answer: you are missing a `return` in the `if` block of `ThreadSafeQueue::get`, and you return the address of a local variable. This is guaranteed to blow up.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I had to copy old part of the code. Fixed

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts to this problem:

#### Uploading images to the GPU on a separate thread

You need to set up an OpenGL context on both your rendering thread and your loading thread, and configure them to share resources. I have only done this with Qt, but [this SDL2 thread](https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=36851) sounds promising. This allows you to call `LoadFromFile` on the loading thread and produce an OpenGL texture ID that is accessible from both contexts.

#### Communicating the result back to another thread

You had the right idea with `std::async`, but then chose to immediately block on it.
Instead, you should store the returned `std::future` somewhere and check if it is `.valid()` on every iteration of your render loop. Once it becomes valid, grab the result and store it in state local to your rendering loop. (ie a local variable) From then on you do not need to check the future anymore, obviously.

A more general mechanism might be to have an `std::map<std::string, GLenum>` that maps texture names to OpenGL texture IDs. Textures that are loaded could be initialized to a known-invalid enum, while loaded textured would contain the texture ID.

Comment: I already know how to upload images to the gpu on a separate thread, but I'd like to know different ways and choose the best one. @geza has suggested to load a image on the loading thread to main memory and upload it to the gpu on the render thread. I need a second to understand second paragraph you wrote.

Comment: I would think uploading textures on the render loop rather defeats the purpose of having a separate loader thread, but you can certainly return `SDL_Surface*` from the loader thread instead of OpenGL texture IDs.

Comment: `you can certainly return SDL_Surface* from the loader thread instead of OpenGL texture IDs` I do not exactly understand it.

Comment: `check if it is .valid() on every iteration of your render loop.` I'd like to create textures before the main/render loop in a constructor for example.

Comment: `I would think uploading textures on the render loop rather defeats the purpose of having a separate loader thread` so I have to upload texture to the gpu on a separate thread if I want my program to load textures while doing something else and there is not way around?

Comment: @JarekBisnesu: "*I'd like to create textures before the main/render loop in a constructor for example.*" No, you don't. "*I have to upload texture to the gpu on a separate thread if I want my program to load textures while doing something else*" ... yes. That's literally what threads are for.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I might sounded wrong. I know that if I want my program to load the texture while doing something else, I have to use threads, but my main goal of this sentence was to make sure I have to upload texture **TO THE GPU** on a separate thread instead of just pixels/surface to main memory and when pixels are ready, upload them to the gpu on the render thread.

Comment: @JarekBisnesu You are contradicting yourself. You cannot "like to create textures before the main/render loop in a constructor for example." and at the same time "run [the render loop] while the texture is loading and when the texture gets loaded, program will render the texture"

Comment: @JarekBisnesu So yes, then your question was about performing OpenGL texture uploads on a separate thread (covered by the first part of my answer) and informing the render thread when that is done (second part)

Comment: "You are contradicting yourself. You cannot "like to create textures before the main/render loop in a constructor for example." and at the same time "run [the render loop] while the texture is loading and when the texture gets loaded, program will render the texture"" I can. I am doing it right now, at this moment. To not edit post with the shitcode I will paste it on pastebin  https://pastebin.com/9mk4eNfM

Comment: In that example `texture` is just a placeholder for the texture. Of course you can create that in advance. If you look at it from afar, that is a simpler version of the `std::map` I proposed in my answer. Whether you use shared references to unique_ptrs (which is really a mindfuck if you think about it) or the `std::async`/`std::future` is a matter of implementation.